# How do I keep Paul alive?

Tags: the-password-game

Paul hatched and needs feeding worms. Unfortunately, I tried to be clever and left him with loads of worms while I looked for the next part of the password. I got a game over because Paul was overfed.

How does this work? How many worms is it safe to give him- do I need to return to the tab and paste one every 20 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After receiving Paul in Rule 17, several future rules will put his life in danger. Once you receive Paul in rule 17, place him in the front of your password

The first is Rule 20. For Rule 20, a fire breaks out at the back of your password and quickly begins spreading toward the front. Anything the fire emoji touches as it spreads forward is destroyed; including Paul. This is why I recommended putting Paul in the front of your password. You will have plenty of time to deal with the fire. Simply highlight the fire and then hit the delete key to get rid of it. Keep in mind if you take too long after selecting the fire to hit the delete key, it may spread and therefore require you to select the new fire as well.

Upon reaching Rule 23, Paul will hatch into a chicken. For the rest of The Password Game, you will have to feed him. Paul eats three bug emojis every minute, or one every 20 seconds. Unfortunately, it’s possible to overfeed him. The safest way seems to be putting three bug emojis in front of the chicken emoji every minute. If you forget to do so, Paul will starve and therefore end your current run of The Password Game.